# Can org protocol capture have multiline content

Tags: org-mode

Not sure what's going on here. This is my capture template:

```
  ("j" "Capture RSS to Incoming"
   entry
   (file+headline "~/Org/jay.org" "Incoming")
   "* %c :RSS:\n%(org-link-unescape \"%i\")"
   :immediate-finish t)
```

When I call it with this:

```
(org-protocol-capture "j/aaa/bbb/cccddd")
```

I get what I'd expect, a line like

```
* [[aaa][bbb]] :RSS:
  cccddd
```

but when I call it with this:

```
(org-protocol-capture "j/aaa/bbb/ccc%0Addd")
```

I get the error:

> byte-code: Capture abort: (end-of-file)

So somehow it seems it does not like the initial content, %i, to have multiple lines.
Can anyone clue me in to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Multi-line content seems to be supported.  Which version of emacs and org-mode are you using?

Using a recent version of emacs and org-mode, I cannot reproduce the error.
invoke a clean emacs:

```
$ emacs -q
```

steps to reproduce:

```
(require 'org-capture)
(require 'org-protocol)

(message (emacs-version))
(org-version nil t t)

(customize-set-variable
 'org-capture-templates
 (quote (("j" "Capture RSS to Incoming"
          entry
          (file+headline "~/tmp/jay.org" "Incoming")
          "* %c :RSS:\n%(org-link-unescape \"%i\")"
          :immediate-finish t))))

(kill-new "Test headline" t)

(org-protocol-capture "j/aaa/bbb/cccddd")
(org-protocol-capture "j/aaa/bbb/ccc%0Addd")
```

Contents of ~/tmp/jay.org is:

```
* Incoming
** Test headline                                                        :RSS:
 cccddd
** Test headline                                                        :RSS:
 ccc
 ddd
```

*Messages* shows:

```
org-capture
org-protocol
GNU Emacs 27.0.50 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.18.9)
 of 2018-06-29
"GNU Emacs 27.0.50 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.18.9)
 of 2018-06-29"
Org mode version 9.1.9 (release_9.1.9-65-g5e4542 @ /usr/share/emacs/27.0.50/lisp/org/)
"Org mode version 9.1.9 (release_9.1.9-65-g5e4542 @ /usr/share/emacs/27.0.50/lisp/org/)"
(("j" "Capture RSS to Incoming" entry (file+headline "~/tmp/jay.org" "Incoming") "* %c :RSS:
%(org-link-unescape \"%i\")" :immediate-finish t))
"Test headline"
(New file)
Clipboard pasted as level 2 subtree
Wrote /home/jeff/tmp/jay.org
Item captured.
nil
Clipboard pasted as level 2 subtree
Wrote /home/jeff/tmp/jay.org
Item captured.
nil
```